# Django Nested Serializer Error: "The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get a json out similar to this:

```
{
   name: Barry Bonds,
   playerListing: {
      best_buy_price: 69,420
   }
}
```

Here is the serializer.py.

```
class PlayerListingForProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PlayerListing
        fields = (
            'best_buy_price',
        )


class PlayerProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    PlayerListingField = PlayerListingForProfileSerializer()
    
    class Meta:
        model = PlayerProfile
        fields = (
            'PlayerListingField',
            'card_id',
            'name',
        )
```

Here is the model.py:

```
class PlayerProfile(models.Model):
    card_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)


class PlayerListing(models.Model):
    player_profile = models.OneToOneField(
        PlayerProfile,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        #db_constraint=False
        null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
    best_buy_price = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

I've had this working before but I can't figure out why it's throwing the error this time;

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `PlayerListingField` on serializer `PlayerProfileSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `PlayerProfile` instance.
Original exception text was: 'PlayerProfile' object has no attribute 'PlayerListingField'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the "field", name it exactly like the related name.

You've `PlayerListing.player_profile` and `PlayerProfile.player_listing`, so the serializer field should be named like this

**this is edited**

```
class PlayerProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    playerlisting = PlayerListingForProfileSerializer() 
    
    class Meta:
        model = PlayerProfile
        fields = (
            'playerlisting ', # don't forget
            'card_id',
            'name',
        )
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but the error is now: "Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `player_listing` on serializer `PlayerProfileSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `PlayerProfile` instance.
Original exception text was: 'PlayerProfile' object has no attribute 'player_listing'."

Comment: this wouldn't work since PlayerListing.player_profile (OneToOneField) has no custom related_name such as "player_listing" and by default it is only accessible through lowercase name of the target model without underscore seperator. 
Example usage:
    player_listing_instance.playerprofile

Comment: @KutayAslan -thanks! changing player_listing to playerlisting did the trick!

Comment: @KutayAslan is talking absolutely right, the `playerlisting` is called related name and the default is the `model_name.lower()`. If you want to change it, in the model field (where you usually add null, blank, ...) add `related_name="player_listing"`

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the "source" argument to PlayerListingForProfileSerializer inside PlayerProfileSerializer like below:

```
PlayerListingField = PlayerListingForProfileSerializer(source="playerlisting")
```

For further information check out the example from official django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/
(see the "p1.restaurant" example)

Comment: I made that change but still getting this error;

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `PlayerListingField` on serializer `PlayerProfileSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `PlayerProfile` instance.
Original exception text was: 'PlayerProfile' object has no attribute 'playerprofile'.

Comment: ah my mistake, it would be playerlisting not playerprofile (edited the answer) @JeremyE